# Is there a method to map screens

Tags: javascript, react-native

I was creating a quiz app using react native. For that I need 10 screens with different questions and options(i.e. same layout. Only questions and options are changed). So for achieving this, is there any method to map through each element of array of questions and display it in each screen respectively ? Or do I need to achieve it manually?  (I am using stack navigator for navigation)

Comment: you can render the same question screen but pass different values (ie the questions and and the options) to your questions screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass current question number as `index` when you navigation to question/answers screen - first time pass `0`.
Then show question like `QuestionArray[index]`. And when you want to go to next question just increase index by `1` and push same screen to navigation with `index` and so on. You can check current index value before pushing the screen to navigation stack that if value is already `9`, calculate the result and replace stack with result screen

Comment: Thank You for the answer. This helped me to solve the problem ❤️

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Flatlist`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist) to map through each element

```
<Flatlist
 data={QuizArr}
 renderItem={({ Ques, Ans, onNext })=><RenderQuiz {...{ Ques, Ans, onNext }} />}
 keyExtractor={item => item.id}
/>
```

```
RenderQuiz=({ Ques, Ans, onNext })=>{
 return(
   // Your Code
 )
}
```